# Is there a way to edit/show custom properties in Google Drive in the Details tab?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am setting custom properties via Google Drive API (File.appProperties and/or File.properties). I am able to retrieve them via API, but is there a way to edit or at least show those custom properties in Google Drive in the Details tab?

Answer (score 1):

When you perform [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) or [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) try specifying "files(appProperties)" in the `fields` parameter to return your custom properties.

Comment: I am able retrieve them via API, but I don't see them on Google Drive in Details section. I would like users to see the custom properties in Google Drive....

Comment: I think it falls in your hands to retrieve that custom property using the API and create your own custom interface, your own UI (like an HTML page coded by you), where you can display those properties since their already available. I don't think the default Google Drive app doesn't display custom properties.